# About using pointers for 2D array definition in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

When we're defining a 2D array as in:

```
int *a[5];
```

Which dimension does the "5" define? The first or the second?

Comment: check my answer converting to postfix expression will help you to understand complicated declarations :)

Comment: Follow the [clockwise rule](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C+clockwise+rule): start with the variable name `a` and go clockwise through the definition elements; thus, start with "a" - next is `[5]` - "is an array of 5" - continuing clockwise we get to `*` - "pointer to" - continuing clockwise we go all the way around until we hit `int` - "int". Now, concatenate together all the element definitions in double-quotes, and you get "a is an array of 5 pointer to int".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `a[i]` points to a single `int`, which may be the first element in a sequence of `int` objects, like so:

```
 a[0] a[1] a[2] a[3] a[4]
+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+
  |    |    |    |    |
  |    |    |   ...  ...
  |    |    +-------------------------------+
  |    +-------------------+                |
  +-------+                |                |
          |                |                |
          v                v                v
        +---+            +---+            +---+
a[0][0] |   |    a[1][0] |   |    a[2][0] |   |
        +---+            +---+            +---+
a[0][1] |   |    a[1][1] |   |    a[2][1] |   |
        +---+            +---+            +---+
         ...              ...              ...
```

Thus, each `a[i]` can represent a "row" in your structure.  You can dynamically allocate each "row" as

```
a[i] = malloc( sizeof *a[i] * row_length_for_i );
```

or you can set it to point to an existing array:

```
int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int bar[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
...
a[0] = foo;
a[1] = bar;
```

As shown in the example above, each "row" may have a different length.

I keep putting scare quotes around "row" because what you have is not a true 2D array - it's not a *contiguous* sequence of elements.  The object immediately following `a[0][N-1]` will *most likely not* be `a[1][0]`.  What you have is a sequence of pointers, each of which *may* point to the first element of a sequence of `int`, or to a single `int`, or to nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for your complete explanations:)

Answer (score 5):

It's not a "2D" array. It's a 1-dimensional array of pointers to `int`. As such the array size designates that it has space for 5 pointers. Each individual pointer can point to the first element of a buffer with different size.

A "true 2D array" is the colloquial "array of arrays" `int a[M][N]`. Here the expression `a[i]` evaluates to the array of `N` integers, at position `i`.

Comment: **a is for access to 2D array ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi - In relation to the OP, it accesses the integer pointed to by the first element in the array. The first `*` makes the array decay to a pointer and dereferences it (obtaining a pointer to an `int`). The second `*` obtains the `int` from the previously obtained pointer.

Comment: No comment about the down-vote? And right after I criticized another answer? I smell vote fraud.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi - didn't think you did. It's just an issue with some of my posts as of late.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations sir. (I up-voted you but Mr.Bode's answer was more complete:))

Comment: @B.Gh - It was certainly better illustrated :)